# How to create event over multiply days with the onSelectSlot method from react-big-calendar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

I need to create an events that starts at one day and ends at another.
I want to use the OnSelectSlot method from react-big-Calendar.

Example event

- Start: Monday 13:00
- List Ends : Wednesday 13:00
- Title: TEST-Seminar

The problem is that i can only select timeslots on one day to a maximal time of 23:59:59
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4au1U.png).

```js
//React hooks for events and selected week
const [events, setEvents] = useState([])
const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date())
<Calendar
    showMultiDayTimes={true}
    selectable={true}
    views={['week']}
    defaultView='week'
    defaultDate={selectedDate}
    events={events}
    onNavigate={(date) => setSelectedDate(new Date(date))}
    onSelectSlot={(event) => console.log(event)}
    onSelecting={(event) => console.log(event)}
/>
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How to create event over multiply days with the onSelectSlot method from react-ig-calendar? I cant select over multiple days but i need to.